# How to upgrade django?

Tags: python, django

My project was running on Django 1.5.4 and I wanted to upgrade it. I did `pip install -U -I django` and now `pip freeze` shows Django 1.6.5 (clearly django has upgraded, I'm in `virtualenv`) but my project is still using Django 1.5.4. How can I use the upgraded version?

UPDATE: Thanks for your comments. I tried everything but unfortunately nothing worked and I had to re-deploy the app.

Hope someone explains why this happened.

Comment: `pip uninstall django` and then `pip install django`. Maybe Your project is running under another virtualenv'y ?

Comment: Have you restarted the server process?

Comment: Not sure if this is the problen, but there's a bug in virtualenv that if you use django-admin.py it will use the system version. Instead, always use `python django-admin.py <command>`  and `python manage.py <command>`. The initial python command will make sure it uses the environment django at all times

Comment: If you are using virtualenv be sure that you activate the environment before upgrade

Answer (score 103):

You can use `--upgrade` with the `pip` command to upgrade Python packages.

```
pip install --upgrade django==3.3.1
```

Answer (score 40):

I use this command for upgrading any package using pip:

```
pip install <package-name> --upgrade
```

Example: `pip install django --upgrade`

you need to use the **`--upgrade`** or **`-U`** flag for upgrading.

Alternatively, you can use `python -m pip install -U Django`.

Answer (score 13):

1. Use this command to get all available Django versions: `yolk -V django`
2. Type `pip install -U Django` for latest version, or if you want to specify version then use `pip install --upgrade django==1.6.5`

**NOTE:** Make sure you test locally with the updated version of Django before updating production.

Answer (score 8):

You can use **pip install -U django**. It will update to the current stable version. Read official documentation on [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/upgrade-version/)

Answer (score 5):

with python 3.7 try:

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade django==2.2.6
```

Because using the following:

```
pip3 install -U django
```

or with python 2.7 if you like to keep that old python:

```
pip install -U django
```

Only gives you the older version of django (1.11.xx instead of 2.2.6)

Answer (score 4):

```
pip install --upgrade django
```

works just fine, but before upgrading it's highly recommended to read this part from the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/upgrade-version/

Answer (score 3):

I'm not an expert on either Python or Django.

What I am doing is following along this really very good book: [Test Driven Web Development With Python (2nd Ed)](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Test-Driven-Development-Python-Harry-Percival/dp/1491958707/ref=la_B00M77PKUO_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1514576252&sr=1-1). It uses Django...

I'm also using a Windoze machine (W10) with Cygwin.

The reason I mention all this is because I found, having installed Python 3.6 in my Cygwin setup, that I had to use ***pip3***, not `pip`, to install Django.

My installed version of Django was 1.11.8.  To follow the "official" (?) tutorial [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/) they want you to have Django 2.0 installed. I successfully managed to do this with:

```
$ pip3 install -U django
```

Hope this helps someone. Perhaps someone much more knowledgeable than me can talk about the need or otherwise to use `pip3` for all Python 3.x activity???

Comment: "requests 2.18.4 has requirement certifi>=2017.4.17 but you'll have
certif 0.0.8 which is incompatible."

Answer (score 3):

The method outlined in the docs is correct -
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/upgrade-version/

What I can add to the above answers is the rationale. If you're very far behind in Django versions *(ex. 1.5 -> and you want to go to 2.0)* **the developers only want you to upgrade one step at a time.** *ex. 1.5 -> 1.6 -> 1.7 etc.*

The purpose being that this limits the amount of things that break on upgrading. You should include the `-Wa` warning flags every time you upgrade a step, so you can fix deprecated features before they are removed in future upgrades.

A feature is generally deprecated for a couple of versions, and then removed entirely. So this gives you the ability to keep the app stable while upgrading.

Answer (score 3):

**How to upgrade Django Version**

python -m pip install -U Django

> **use cammand on CMD**

Answer (score 2):

**sudo pip install --upgrade django**

*also upgrade the DjangoRestFramework:*

**sudo pip install --upgrade djangorestframework**

Answer (score 2):

I think after updating your project, you have to restart the server.

Answer (score 2):

`pip3 install django -U`

this will uninstall django, and then install the latest version of django.

---

pip3 is if you use python3.

**-U** is shortcut for **--upgrade**

Comment: That was simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the upgraded version after upgrading.

You should check that all your tests pass before deploying :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command in vitualenv:

```
 `pip install django==<version>`
```

this should work.

Answer (score 0):

you must do the following:
1- Update pip 
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
2- If you already install Django update by using the following command
pip install --upgrade Django
or you can uninstall it using the following command
pip uninstall Django
3- If you don't install it yet use the following command
python -m pip install Django
4- Type your code

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

From the Django Docs: if you are using a Virtual Environment and it is a major upgrade, you might want to set up a new environment with the dependencies first.
Or, if you have installed Django using the PIP, then the below is for you:
`python3.8 -m pip install -U Django` .

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, when I upgraded my ubuntu 18.04 to 20, by default in the latest version of ubuntu django=2.2.12 pre-installed, but I'm working on the latest Django version=3.1, so I need to upgrade that to 3.1.

Here is a solution:

python 3.8.5

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade django==3.1.7
```

Now check your all pre-installed versions with python

```
pip list
```

Comment: I've tried this, it may just be my docker setup but the above command uninstalls Django (as part of the upgrade) but fails to reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade Django using the below command.

```
python -m pip install -U Django
```

Answer (score 0):

If you working with Django + React and getting such a error... you forgot to collect static files:

```bash
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Answer (score -2):

new version in django :-

pip install Django==4.0.2