# How to update package/dependencies on live django website?

Tags: django, digital-ocean, django-deployment, django-packages

I have created a django website which now I am looking to deploy through DigitalOcean, I have not uploaded it yet because I want to get a clear picture before actually starting.
My questions are,

1. How to I update the packages required for my website once I have deployed my website?
   Eg: I am using CKEditor 6. In future, when CKEditor 7 arrives how do I update the package so that my
   website uses the latest CKEditor without losing any data.
2. DigitalOcean deployment works with and without git right? So should I skip git, because I really do not
   care about versioning my website. Simple update through FTP apps(WinSCP, Filezilla) will work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking remote server is no different from a local machine what stays in your bedroom. Yes, it doesn't have monitor, yes, it is a rack with a lot of wires and yes, it is usually far away from you, but afterall the logic is the same. Thus everything works almost the same way it does on your local computer. **Yes**, you will be able to update dependencies, **yes** you will be able to not use git. But the fact you may not use git, doesn't mean that you should not. Also you will have to think of another DB, proxy server and intermediary between such and django app.

Comment: Thanks for simplifying it. This is the question  
 https://stackoverflow.com/q/23708895/12806577  which made me ask my question. Because the answers answered over there are confusing. Some say -U command will work, some say you have to create new virtual environment. I don't want to lose my data once my site is live.